# Angle between left and right tangent to the graph

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

I am supposed to determine the angle between the left and the right tangent to the graph g, in the point $$\left [ 1, \frac{\sqrt{3}\pi }{6} \right ]$$where $$g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arcsin \frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}$$
I tried to do first derivation, which is equal to $$ \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3+3x^{2}}$$
and limits: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}} \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3+3x^{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}} \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3+3x^{2}}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$ but I do not know, what to do next.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I got this here $$g'(x)=-2/3\,{\frac {\sqrt {3} \left( x-1 \right)  \left( x+1 \right) }{
 \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {{\frac { \left( x-1
 \right) ^{2} \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}
}}}}}$$

Comment: Note that $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$

Comment: thanks, do you have some clue how to continue, or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the correct derivative is

$$g'(x) = \frac{-2(x-1)(x+1)}{\sqrt3 (x^2+1)\cdot |x-1| \cdot |x+1|}$$

However, your limits are correct. Considering that the derivative $g'(x)$ is equal to the slope of the tangent at the point $(x, g(x))$, the angle between the tangent and the $x$ axis is $\alpha=\arctan(g'(x))$.

Hence, if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are the angles of the left tangent and the right tangent respectively, then the angle between them is
$$\alpha_1-\alpha_2 = \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{3}\right) - \arctan\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}{3}\right) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$